# Call Worklight Javascript SQL Adapter form REST Client

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using IBM Worklight 7.1 and I am trying to call a Javascript SQL adapter form REST client like HttpRequester. I can call adapter but cannot figure out how to pass parameters to procedure.

For Adapter named `MyAdapter` and procedure named `myProc`, I can call adapter using `baseUrl/MyAdapter/myProc`, using both `GET` and `POST` method form REST Client, but all the parameters in procedure are `undefined`.

```
function myProc(a,c) {      
        return {
            result : "OK"
        };
}
```

I have tried passing parameter in following ways.

1. As query string `?a=b&c=d`
2. As JSON String `{"a":"b","c":"d"}`
3. Passing parameter in array as parameters=['b','c']

---

**Why Do This**

Reason behind doing this is to make *Data Setting*, *Procedure call*, *Output check* and *data erase* process automatic by writing script to make testing easy and automatic. So, feel free to suggest if any other better process already exist to do above steps automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a JavaScript adapter (this answer is not applicable to Java adapters), the REST call should look like:

```
/{project-context}/adapters/{adapter-name}/{procedure-name}/?params=[a,b,c,d]
```

In other words, a JavaScript procedure receives only ONE parameter called `params` which needs to be an array of ordered, unnamed values.

Comment: I've added a paragraph here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/adapter-framework-overview/#TestingAdapters

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question is, If my parameters are too long they might be problematic. Is there a way to pass them with POST method?

Comment: Yes, use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and set the body to `params=[a,b,c]`